# Is it possible in Java read files placed in a Jar that it's placed in a Ear too?

Tags: java, jakarta-ee, jar

I was wondering if is possible to find the content in an XML file placed in a jar thath is placed in a ear too. It would help me find the properties of java beans.

Up into the ear I can iterate through documents and see what's inside, but if it is a jar I can't iterate documents inside that.

Someone can give me some advice?

Comment: Are you talking about JAR in JAR, or JAR in EAR, or JAR in JAR in EAR? The question title contradicts the question message. The answer to question title is "no", the answer to question message is "yes". Detailed advice depends on the context which is entirely unclear. "scroll through documents" makes no sense. What exactly is the functional requirement and use case?

Comment: I assumed he has a jar file packaged in a ear file. But you are right BalusC, the title contradicts the question. I didn't notice that.

Comment: @CoolBeans: so, you interpreted "scroll through documents" as "using Windows explorer to view files in EAR/JAR"? This isn't a programming question at all and the title starts with "Is it possible in Java" ...

Comment: Oh, did he mean to extract a jar file programatically like using java.util.jar.JarFile ?

Comment: @CoolBeans: I don't know. This question is definitely unclear and not useful.

Comment: Agreed. Should I vote to delete my post? Cause I think my answer is also unclear since the question itself is unclear.

Comment: i think he meant to ask about resolving an XML file placed within a JAR, which in turn is packaged within an EAR.

Comment: @all: sorry i amiss the correct meaning of the question. I have an EAR which contains some jar. Via java i want to retrieve an .xml located in a jar folder.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From the ear file you should be able to extract the jar file. Then you can use [WinZip](http://www.winzip.com/win/en/index.htm), [7 Zip](http://www.7-zip.org/), etc to do explore the jar file contents the GUI. Or you can run the [jar tf](http://download.oracle.com/javase/1.4.2/docs/tooldocs/solaris/jar.html) command to extract the content of the jar file in command line. If you don't have any of these tools and using windows, then you can rename the jar file to a .zip and windows should be able to explore it (most of the cases it works).

Edits - I am not sure if you wanted to do it using Java. In that case you are looking for [JarFile](http://download.oracle.com/javase/1.4.2/docs/api/java/util/jar/JarFile.html). I found an [example](http://www.devx.com/tips/Tip/22124) of it here for exploring Jar contents programatically.

Comment: i think the OP wants to do this programmatically.

Answer (score 1):

so i just tested the thing you want to do - and as long as the JAR lies in the classpath of your EAR, then you can access any file within it. basically the try to look up the file from the context-root of your application.

for example if in your JAR the file `abc.xml` resides under the package `a.b.resources`, then from say a servlet in your EAR you can access it using :
`InputStream is = this.getClass().getClassLoader().getResourceAsStream("a/b/resources/abc.properties");`

Comment: `abc.xml` != `abc.properties`, plus it's in multi-classloader environments more recommended to use the thread context's classloader rather than the class' one.

Comment: agree on the multi-classloader env part, but the _.properties_ was a typo.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you can read any file that is packed into zip file. It does not matter how many nested zip file you have to open on your way. Use ZipInputStream, get needed ZipEntry, read it content. If it is still zip, open it and do it again and again until you access the required resource.